What are the authentic sources for Shabri mantras( VIdya vardhan) and how to make them powerful
Shabri mantras created by Lord Goraksha Nath(2nd in Nath Parampara) has written some powerful mantras, are there any authentic source and how to make them effective for increasing Knowledge and cognitive intelligence.
